# What does the submit button do, and how do you make a signup for newsletter with it?

Tags: html, email, newsletter, submit-button

I've been coding a website, it's nearly finished but I want users to be able to sign up for a newsletter. I've found that you can use the submit button but I don't know how to. How do you get the button to email you the information? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-create-a-newsletter-from-scratch-using-PHP-and-MySQL.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the page contains a series of input elements ( think text boxes etc) which the user puts their data in to, the submit button POSTs a form to the server, the server can then access those form values and use them as required.

So in your scenario the server received an email address and name, for example, and you have an email library which can send that information to you. Alternatively of course you might put that information in a database so you can more easily handle subscriptions.

Comment: Thank you very much- it has helped.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial how get user email and save in database.
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1924985